# Javascript - Get an element regarding its data-slug

Tags: javascript

I have on a webpage several buttons like that :

```
<div class="jet-portfolio__filter-item" data-slug="slug-one">
<div class="jet-portfolio__filter-item" data-slug="slug-two">
```

I'm catching a slug parameter passed in url that tells me which button I should click on page load.
Question is how can I get the right button using javascript, since they don't have ids, to click it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all elements by class name with "getElementByClassName" and then looping all elements and do addEventListenet to all selected items and pass a function to get the attribute of each element when the user does click.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("jet-portfolio__filter-item");

var onClickItems = function() {
    var slug = this.getAttribute("data-slug");
    console.log(slug)
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', onClickItems);
}
```

```html
<div class="jet-portfolio__filter-item" data-slug="slug-one">Container number 1</div>
<div class="jet-portfolio__filter-item" data-slug="slug-two">Container number 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very simple with the onclick JS function. Then you have two options for reading out the data element. 1) getAttribute() and 2) dataset

```js
function myFn(elem) {
  console.log('with getAttribute:', elem.getAttribute('data-slug'))
  console.log('with dataset:', elem.dataset.slug)  
}
```

```html
<div class="jet-portfolio__filter-item" data-slug="slug-one" onclick="myFn(this)">click me! Slug One</div>      
<div class="jet-portfolio__filter-item" data-slug="slug-two" onclick="myFn(this)">click me! Slug Two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use attribute selector to select those elements (assuming you're not using their classes to select them).

Here's the `CSS` attribute selector syntax: `tag[attribute=value]`.
I think you can also replace `tag` with `class` or `id` but I'm not sure.

Now you can use this syntax in `document.querySelector(selector)`.

```js
const slugOne = document.querySelector("div[data-slug=slug-one]");

console.log(slugOne.innerText);
```

```html
<div data-slug="slug-one">Content Of Slug One</div>
<div data-slug="slug-two">Content Of Slug Two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (just click on Text #1 or Text #2):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.jet-portfolio__filter-item')
.forEach(el => el.onclick = () => console.log(el.innerText, el.dataset.slug));
```

```html
<div class="jet-portfolio__filter-item" data-slug="slug-one">Text #1</div>
<div class="jet-portfolio__filter-item" data-slug="slug-two">Text #2</div>
```